# Как исправить ошибку invalid syntax в коде связанную с f'

Tags: python

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM( 'Мой API, на всякий случай замазал', language = "ru")

place = input("В каком городе? ")

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print  ("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + str(temp))
```

А вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Weather.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyowm
  File "C:\Users\Саша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyowm\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyowm.owm import OWM
  File "C:\Users\Саша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyowm\owm.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyowm.weatherapi25 import weather_manager
  File "C:\Users\Саша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\weather_manager.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyowm.weatherapi25 import forecaster, historian, observation, forecast, stationhistory, one_call
  File "C:\Users\Саша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\observation.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pyowm.weatherapi25 import weather
  File "C:\Users\Саша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\weather.py", line 466
    temperature[f'feels_like_{label}'] = temp
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: Судя по путям - у вас Python 3.5, а f-strings появились с версии 3.6.

Comment: @GrAnd Спасибо огромное, поставил Python 3.6 и всё заработало. От души)

Comment: @MySashaLolKek ты мог и другие конструкции использовать. `format`, например

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Он то мог. Вот только облом случился не в его коде, а в коде стороннего модуля _pyowm_.